# Get an array of annotations on a entity class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to get a list of annotations used on my entity class in symfony 6 using doctrine 2.11+

The class

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\IncentriMenu;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocParser;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Reader;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Doctrine\Deprecations\Deprecation;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

class EntityReaderController extends AbstractController{

    private EntityManagerInterface $em;
    private Reader $annotationReader;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, Reader $annotationReader){
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->annotationReader = $annotationReader;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/", methods={"GET","HEAD"})
     */
    public function reader(): Response
    {
        $classes = array();
        $docParser = new DocParser();
        //$docParser->setImports(["Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints","Doctrine\ORM\Mapping"]);
        //$docParser->addNamespace("Doctrine\ORM\Mapping");
        //$docParser->addNamespace("Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints");
        $annotationReader = new AnnotationReader();
        $annotations = $annotationReader->getClassAnnotations(new \ReflectionClass(Menu::class));
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($annotations);
        echo "</pre>";

        $annotations2 = $this->annotationReader->getClassAnnotations(new \ReflectionClass(Menu::class));
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($annotations2);
        echo "</pre>";

        return new Response("Done");
    }
}
```

This is what i have tried so far. But the return empty.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity Object
        (
            [repositoryClass] => 
            [readOnly] => 
        )

    [1] => Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table Object
        (
            [name] => incentrimenu
            [schema] => 
            [indexes] => 
            [uniqueConstraints] => 
            [options] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity Object
        (
            [repositoryClass] => 
            [readOnly] => 
        )

    [1] => Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table Object
        (
            [name] => incentrimenu
            [schema] => 
            [indexes] => 
            [uniqueConstraints] => 
            [options] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Annotations in my menu class is:

```
   /**
    * @var string|null
    *
    * @Assert\Type("string")
    * @Assert\NotBlank
    * @ORM\Column(name="menu", type="string")
    */
    private $menu;
```

Please help me find a solution that returns an array with the correct annotations.
Possible annotations that standard like asserts.

Comment: Looks like you're only calling `getClassAnnotations` which only applies to annotations related to `class Menu` vs `getPropertyAnnotations` which applies to annotation related to `private $menu`.

Comment: Thank you I`ll check out getPropertyAnnotations and come back to you on that.

Comment: Thank you @WillB. 
Adding this:
$propertyAnnotations = $annotationReader->getPropertyAnnotations(new \ReflectionProperty(Menu::class,"menu"));
Gives me the annotations of menu.